# Why does youtube/chrome randomly resume play on paused video?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, youtube

I have observed for a while now that if I leave a youtube page with a paused video, sometimes that video will randomly unpause by itself over a certain length of time (in the order of a few hours).

Why does youtube (on chrome) do this? And is there a way to prevent the video from unpausing randomly?

I have observed this mainly with the ABC News webpage at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIYb-7HxDSI

Comment: I have the same issue, found it on YouTube using chrome watching the most hilarious peppa pig 5 mill times. I still love her though. We might need to take that up with chrome-linux themselves.

Answer (score 5):

I've found one solution :')

For me it was my headphones jack triggering playback
– it was misreading my headphone jack input
and playing videos, even in the background –
so, on Chrome, I've disabled media key input:

Type in `chrome://flags`.

Find 'Hardware Media Key Handling'
and disable it.

This was on a Windows PC.

Comment: My laptop was resuming YouTube videos that were paused over the last few months any time I put it to sleep/suspend - this has fixed it!

Comment: For it was my Alexa Echo Dot 4th Gen causing this annoying behavior found a solution here https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/g6uknz/anyone_else_having_issues_pausing_vlc_on_windows/fqi5gqm/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Find it in [Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers]. Then [Properties -> Services] and untick Remote Control.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when Windows is signed out and the screen is dark. It's happened a few times, usually in the middle of the night. The last time it happened, my headphones had broken a few days before so no headphones were connected.

Comment: This does not really answer the questions asked. Can you elaborate on how to prevent this from happening, if indeed this still happens?

Comment: Same here. Closed notebook even. No Bluetooth device switched on.